# Mercurial list all files changed during last update

Tags: mercurial

Is there a command to list all files that changed during the last **update**?

```
hg status --change tip
```

gives me just the files of the last **changeset**.

I could use

```
hg status --rev FROM --rev TO
```

but then I'd have to store the rev from before the update.

Comment: Alternatively you could run `hg status --rev . --rev tip` prior to doing the update, so you'll at least know what _will_ change. But as Tim Delaney says, you don't really have a way to do this after the event.

Answer (score 4):

You could work out what will change *prior* to performing an `hg update` by doing a status and passing in the current and `tip` revisions: `hg status --rev . --rev tip`.

This will show you what files *will* change when you perform an update, but won't have any effect after the update, as mentioned by Tim Delaney.  I am assuming that you want to know what has changed as you are doing an update after a pull?  In which case it may be better to know what will change *before* you do the update anyway.

Comment: I wanted to know it because I want to run a script on the updated files. But so I have to store the list first, run the update and then execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

No. Mercurial does not store any information about the previous state of the working directory once an update has been performed. During an update it may store some state to help with recovering after an interrupted update, but nothing that would be useful for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial doesn't keep track of how often you run `hg update`, so it can't tell you which files were touched by the last update. However, it also doesn't mess with the modtimes of the affected files, so you can look at their timestamps to see what changed. To figure out which files were modified in the last five minutes, use

```
find . -mmin -5 -print
```

The alternative would be to record what mercurial *will* update, as @icabod suggested.

Comment: I would have expected that there would be a simple command for that. But thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Mercurial tracks the history of your project, not the state of your local copy; `hg update` moves you up and down the revision tree but has no effect on the project history.

Comment: I find this one liner very informative on which files were changed over the course of the last 14 days

`for i in {1..14}; do echo $i; find . -mtime $i -print; done`

or in the last 30 minutes if I don't remember the exact time I updated.

`for i in {1..30}; do echo $i; find . -mmin $i -print; done`

Comment: @RaamEE, isn't `find . -mtime -14 -ls` good enough for you? It tells you which files were changed in the last two weeks, and when. Or perhaps ``ls -lt `find . -mtime -14` ``, if you want them in order of modification? I don't see the point of running `find` 14 times.

Comment: @alexis, the outputs for the commands are different. I simply like better the output from my version, because that way I group files by how old they are. 1st group of files 1 days old, then another group of files 2 days old and so on. Your command provides  all the files changed during the last 14 days in one group. (BTW, to improve the output on my one liner, better start the count from 0 instead of 1)

Comment: As I said, the second version I offered (with `ls -lt`) orders the files by age. Your code is longer (which only matters if you're typing it in on the fly) and slower, but hey you can use whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

If *after* you do "hg update" you want to find out what changed during the update, you might try this:

First, use "hg log -l nn" to get a list of the revisions that are part of the most recent update.

Next, use "hg diff -r nn" to show all the differences since the revision *before* the update.

And, if you just want a summary of the files that changed, then use "hg diff --stat -r nn".